# How would I go about acquiring the transparent overlay for the iPhone's home screen icons?

Tags: iphone, icons, transparent

I'd like to have the home screen style for a section of my app, and the icon style will most likely be the 'make it or break it' aspect.  Right now, I've got it looking pretty decent.  I just have a black background with rounded buttons and the basic system text under them as labels.  With a few modifications to [this psd kit](http://www.keepthewebweird.com/iphone-icon-psd-template/) I've been able to make relatively decent looking ripoff icons.  I just think they would look that much better if I could get the actual thing.  Is it possible to get the overlay that apple uses without getting sued?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These images are stored in a packed binary file inside UIKit. If you have a jailbroken device, you can generate the images by installing Winterboard and running `/Applications/Winterboard.app/UIImages` from MobileTerminal or an SSH session. Alternatively, you can try and get saurik's [UIImages source](http://svn.saurik.com/repos/menes/trunk/winterboard/UIImages.mm) to work from inside an Xcode project.

Note: distributing these images isn't completely legal
<sup>(this is why I have not included them in this answer)</sup>

Comment: Well that sucks.  Thanks for clearing this up though.  Unfortunately I don't have a jailbroken device, and I do intend to distribute my app, so it probably wouldn't be a good idea to include them.  Do you think my ripoff icons would perhaps prevent my app from being approved for the app store?

Comment: I don't think imitation icons would, but an imitated home screen might.

Comment: Okay, cool.  I think it's pretty obvious in my app that it's not imitating the home screen.  We're just trying to get the same sort of style so it all kind of flows together.